Account linking with next-auth / Multiple sign in pages?
I am having a next app and I am using next-auth. I want to enable the account linking for when a user is already logged in. For example, a user is already signed in, and in the /settings page he can click to connect another account, let's say a google account.
My problem is that I don't understand how to show to the user that an error occured ( For example, when an account is already linked to another user ).
These are my pages from configuration:
  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/login',
    error: '/auth/error',
  },

so, the /auth/login is used for when a user logs in, and on my /settings page I have this component:
export const GoogleSignInButton = () => {
  const onClick = async (callbackUrl?: string) => {
    console.log({ callbackUrl });
    if (callbackUrl) {
      try {
        signIn('google', { callbackUrl: callbackUrl });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('CAUGHT ERROR: ', error);
      }
    }
  };
  return (
    <Button
      size='lg'
      className='w-full'
      variant='outline'
      onClick={() => onClick('http://localhost:3000/settings')}
    >
      <FcGoogle className='h-5 w-5' />
    </Button>
  );
};

which purpose is to display a button for an already logged in user to try and sign in via google and thus linking that account.
The problem is that even though I specified the callback url to be the /settings page ( I thought that doing so, will behave like the login page, where the error code is attached as ?error='....' to the baseurl ), the user is still redirected to the actual login page ( '/auth/login' ) which is not actually desired.
So what should I do?
Also, I have this middleware who automically redirects already logged in users to the /settings page if they try to access the /auth/login route.
Any idea on how to manage this?
